# How to enable MySQL remote access?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server and I want to enable remote access for a certain IP and localhost only. For some reason I couldn't manage to do it as it doesn't work every time I try. I typed the following command (of course user, password and db where different):

`mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'192.168.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';`

I also disabled `skip-networking`.

What am I doing wrong then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the bind-address parameter to the IP you wish to allow remote access to.  However, most people just comment out the bind-address parameter in the my.cnf file to allow access from anywhere and deal with who can access the DB server with user access control.  I would suggest the latter and not the former. Don't forget to restart mysql server after making changes to my.cnf for the changes to take effect.

Please refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql) for more information.

Additionally, The grant statement should have single quotes around the name as well as the host:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO 'bar'@'192.168.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Also, don't forget to

```
Flush privileges;
```